# Are there docker remote api command line client's

Tags: java, docker, boot2docker

I'm interested in supporting developers using docker as part of their local workflow.  Most of them are on Windows and OSX and would be using *Boot2Docker* to run docker.

The source of the images are located on the host computers alongside the project source code.

There is no way (without messing with the *Boot2Docker* image to add guest additions, or running a samba container) to share a host directory into the *Boot2Docker* VM so I want to use the remote API for the same effect.

i.e. dev builds maven project on the host which results in a .war artifact being created.

A Dockerfile is created on the host to build an image that can deploy that .war artifact.

I want a command line tool that I can run on the host that will let me invoke the build image command against that *Dockerfile* and related files so that I get a runnable image inside of the *Boot2Docker* VM.

There are a variety of libraries that can talk to the docker remote api but I'm having trouble finding tools that I can run directly from the host command line.

I'm considering just writing my own command line interface to the *docker-java* library but wanted to know if there are existing tools that I could use?

Comment: Can su clarify? The docker build already works on the boot2docker vm. The cli basically sends the Dockerfile and context files to the server for the build. So at the end of the `docker build` command, the image already is on your boot2docker vm.

Comment: On the Boot2Docker VM you can use the **docker** command but my docker files are on the windows (or OSX) host file system.

Its my understanding that there are no **docker** commands to run natively in windows or OSX.

ideally I would run docker command natively on the host and point it at the remote api location.  

I'm looking for either a way to do this with the docker command or another cli built on one of the remote api libraries.

Comment: I have same issue, and I prefer to use patched iso to support share folder by just replace official boot2docker.iso with patched iso.  https://medium.com/boot2docker-lightweight-linux-for-docker/boot2docker-together-with-virtualbox-guest-additions-da1e3ab2465c it is not so mess.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have missed that boot2docker provides not only the VM, but also a `docker` binary that can connect to it (see Running Docker section on the Boot2Docker documentation [for OSX](http://docs.docker.com/installation/mac/#running-docker) and [for Windows](http://docs.docker.com/installation/windows/#running-docker).

The `docker` cli (on all and every platform) just communicates with a docker daemon. The default setup is to communicate through a local unix socket, which is considered more secure, but boot2docker comes configured to listen on a TCP socket on the VM, which is preconfigured to be reachable from the host.

When starting recent boot2docker versions (at least on OSX), you get this message with the only configuration you need:

```
$ boot2docker up
2014/07/05 18:23:01 Waiting for VM to be started...

2014/07/05 18:23:02 Started.
2014/07/05 18:23:02 To connect the Docker client to the Docker daemon, please set:
2014/07/05 18:23:02     export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2375
```

If I understand the question, this is all you need, and is all provided by docker and boot2docker.

Comment: For docket client, just uses `docker -H tcp://192.168.59.103:2375` to connect the remote docker daemon.